# css bourbon mixins: should I use always?

Tags: css, sass, mixins, bourbon

I start using sass and bourbon frequently and some thoughts came up in my mind: Should I use as much as possible bourbon mixins?

For example, I have this simple code

```
el {
 @import margin(10px 10px 10px 10px);
}
```

Why should I use bourbon mixin when I can just write

```
el {
 margin: 10px;
}
```

Remember that bourbon does **not** render single-directional property in this case, like so

```
el {
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: In my personal opinion you should not make promiscuous use of such relatively useless mixins. Why would you?

Comment: Exactly, that's why I would like other opinions! I wouldn't use any useless mixins like I've shown! I just want to know if other devs think that it is useless as well.

Comment: The mixins are there to make writing Sass more efficient and easier. I would agree that `margin: 10px` is easier than using the mixin in that case. There should really never be a reason to use a mixin that is less efficient and results in equal but more verbose CSS.